# Add string to certain cells

Tags: excel, vba

I split cells based on defined value in the cell.

I found code on StackOverflow and customized it (another value, worksheet, range, etc.).

```vb
Sub makro()
    Dim r As Range, i As Long, ar
    Set r = Worksheets("List1").Range("A999999").End(xlUp)
    Do While r.Row > 1
        ar = Split(r.Value, "+")
        If UBound(ar) >= 0 Then r.Value = ar(0)
        For i = UBound(ar) To 1 Step -1
            r.EntireRow.Copy
            r.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert
            r.Offset(1).Value = ar(i)
        Next
        Set r = r.Offset(-1)
    Loop
End Sub
```

Now I want to add a string to one of the cells.

Lets say I have list like this:

```
column A                 column B   column C  column D
filename1.pdf            string B   string C  string D
filename2.pdf            string B   string C  string D
filename3+filename4.pdf  string B   string C  string D
```

After the macro is triggered it does this:

```
column A                 column B   column C  column D
filename1.pdf            string B   string C  string D
filename2.pdf            string B   string C  string D
filename3                string B   string C  string D
filename4.pdf            string B   string C  string D
```

I am looking for this:

```
filename1.pdf            string B   string C  string D
filename2.pdf            string B   string C  string D
filename3.pdf            string B   string C  string D
filename4.pdf            string B   string C  string D
```

Also, is there a way to have more values for splitting? So not only one "+" like in my case but also "_" for example?

I tried to add a new character for Split.

Comment: You do realize that `filename3+filename4.pdf` is a valid filename in itself, right?

Comment: `Split` accepts only one separator, but you can do something like `ar = Split(Replace(Replace(r.Value, "_", "+"), "-", "+"), "+")`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```vb
Sub makro()
    Const SEP = "+"
    Dim r As Range, i As Long, ar, ext, v
    Set r = Worksheets("List1").Range("A999999").End(xlUp)
    Do While r.Row > 1
        v = r.Value
        NormalizeChars v, Array("_", "~"), SEP 'for example
        ext = "." & Extension(v)
        
        If InStr(v, SEP) Then                  'multiple files?
            v = Left(v, Len(v) - Len(ext))     'remove extension
            ar = Split(v, SEP)
            r.Value = ar(LBound(ar)) & ext
            For i = LBound(ar) + 1 To UBound(ar)
                r.EntireRow.Copy
                r.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert
                r.Offset(1).Value = ar(i) & ext
            Next
        End If
        Set r = r.Offset(-1)
    Loop
End Sub

'return file extension given path/file name `f`
Function Extension(f)
    Extension = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject").getextensionname(f)
End Function

'In `txt`, replace each character in `arrChars` with `toChar`
Sub NormalizeChars(ByRef txt, arrChars, toChar)
    Dim c
    For Each c In arrChars
        txt = Replace(txt, c, toChar)
    Next c
End Sub
```